# How do I dig in a java BSON Document with dots?

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I would like to do the following within java:

```
org.bson.Document document = new Document("foo", new Document("foo2", "foo3");
System.out.println(document.get("foo.foo2"));
```

which would return 'foo3'

This is required for my mongodb java system. 
What would be the easiest way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: `document.get("foo", Document.class).get("foo2")`

Comment: I actually added a wrapper to the Document class that does that exact thing in the backend. And it works.